# preg_replace <strong>apple <strong>tree</strong></strong>

Tags: php, preg-replace

So the problem.. I have been stuck with this one for a good month now, so please any help would be really appreciated.

I am trying to highlight words in a string, from words in an array.  The problem I am having is with nested tags.

```
$bold=array();
$bold="tree,apple tree,orange";
$description="orange and apple tree";
```

For example; `the result I want would be this <strong>orange</strong> and <strong>apple tree</strong>, but the result I am getting is this <strong>orange</strong> and <strong>apple <strong>tree</strong></strong>`

I have cobbled together this so, but it doesn't work as desired, so feel free to amend or trash, if my approach is incorrect.

```
function highlightWords($text, $words){
 foreach ($words as $word){
  $word = preg_quote($word);
  $word = (str_replace("/","",$word));
  $text = preg_replace("/(?!<.*?)(".preg_quote($word,'/').")(?![^<>]*?>)/si",'<strong>\1</strong>', $text);
 }
 return $text;
}
$description =  highlightWords($description, $bold);
```

Comment: What is wrong with the output you gave?

Comment: I want <strong>apple tree</strong> not <strong>apple <strong>tree</strong></strong>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, this is your solution:

```
function highlightWords($text, array $words){
  $words = array_map(preg_quote, $words);
  return preg_replace('/(' . implode('|', $words). ')/is', '<strong>$1</strong>', $text);
}

$text = 'orange and aPPle tree';
$boldWords = array('tree', 'apple tree', 'orange');

$text =  highlightWords($text, $boldWords);
echo $text;
```

Example: http://www.ideone.com/at4lw

You call the function highlightWords with the initial text and an array of words to highlight. The function returns the text with the highlighted words.

Comment: If you don't want to respect capitalize, just use the function `str_ireplace` instead of `str_replace`.

Comment: You anticipated my next question perfectly.. and your code works BUT the ireplace, replaces the case.  Can I keep it in tact?

Comment: Back to where I was now, with the nested <strong> tags.  grrrrr, this is so frustrating.  Any ideas?

Comment: One last try :) Updated again.

Comment: Beautiful!!!!!!!!  Armin, thank you so much this really has been causeing me headaches!!  Not really sure I understand the implode('|', but I can investigate that further so I learn to understand.

Comment: The implode function connects all items of an array with the given glue. `array('a', 'b', 'c')` becomes in this case to: `a|b|c`. This pipe (|) notation is an "or" in regular expressions.

Comment: or, thats the key word.   Thank you again so much Armin.

Answer (score 1):

Great answer. Personally, I'd also mention that you should (or could) modify it to only look for whole words. For example if your $boldWords contained 'ad' and if f your text contained 'lead' and 'had' then you would end up with some oddities.

use \b to add word "boundaries" to only match the entire word.

```
return preg_replace('/\b(' . implode('|', $words). ')\b/is', '<strong>$1</strong>', $text);
```